# Swapping 2 specific JButtons

Tags: java, arrays, button, matrix, swap

I've a quick (or not) question about coding in Java.

Is there a way I could swap the texts in 2 JButtons, or the buttons themselves when I click on just one of them? Like, each button has a specific other button it needs to be replaced with on one click.
Although in my code it's not integers, but strings "X" and "Y".

Here's my code:

```
package game;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int row = 5;
    int col = 5;
    Game gt = new Game(row, col);
    gt.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gt.pack();
    gt.setVisible(true);

  }

  String X = "X";
  String Y = "Y";
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;

  public Game(int row, int col) {
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col));
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
      if(i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 14 || i == 15 || i == 23 || i == 9)
      {
      JButton button = new JButton(X);
      pane.add(button);
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource()==button)
            {
                if(button.getText() == Y) button.setText(X);
                        else button.setText(Y);
            }
            }

      }
      );
      } else if(i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 10 || i == 19 || i == 21 || i == 22){
      JButton button = new JButton(Y);
      pane.add(button);
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource()==button)
            {
                if(button.getText() == Y) button.setText(X);
                    else button.setText(Y);
            }
            }

      });
      } else {
      JButton button = new JButton();
      pane.add(button);
      button.setEnabled(false);
      button.setBorderPainted(false);
      }
    }
  } 
  @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your code seem to be OK some obvious syntax errors. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Well, the code runs the array, so I wouldn't say there's any issue with it.
What I was asking is if there is a way to swap two specific JButtons if I click on just one of them. For example, I have the array like this http://puu.sh/jMukP/a7796f7df6.png ... And when I click on the first X for example, in the first row, I want it to turn to Y and the one on the opposite side (the Y) to turn into X and vice-versa. Just, for the buttons to swap with their opposites.

Comment: Which two buttons do you want to swap? I do not see reference to `other` button in the action listener.

Comment: Well, that's the thing, I've no idea how to do the swap, so the question is how I could do that.  They should swap like this http://puu.sh/jMwYO/ee880bce41.png when I click on just one of them... I tried using for and swapping them in an array with their [i] values, but then I get an error like "the array is only read from never written to" and such.

Answer (score 1):

In this line of code

```
if(button.getText() == Y) button.setText(X);
```

You want to compare the **value** of two `String`, not the **reference**.
I think you should replace the `==` operator by the function `String.equals(Object object)`.

Like this :

```
if(button.getText().equals(Y)) button.setText(X);
```

**EDIT:**

If you have two `String` variables with the same value, they will have the same reference on the value because in Java the `String` are **immutable**. But they will not have the same adress. Here an illustration :

[image: Illustration of the String in Java]

So the `==` operator will compare the **address** of the variable `a` and `b`, not the value. And the function `String.equals(Object object)` will compare the **value** of the variable `a` and `b`.

Comment: Alright, I changed it, works well. What's the difference though? When you compare the values and the references?

Comment: In this case, it doesn't matter whether we use `equals` or `==` - though I agree that using `equals` is more idiomatic and should be preferred.

Comment: Ah, okay, I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are using == instead of String1.equals(String2). This can be used to compare the Strings.
On comparison here you are only exchanging the texts on the String. You mentioned about changing the buttons as such. I did not understand as such. May be you wanted to create another button in the same place. Then you can create another Button object with same position coordinates and make the current button hidden (change visibility).

Comment: I was directed towards that issue above, but thank you either way. Well, no, I'd like to make it so that 2 buttons swap positions or just their texts like this http://puu.sh/jMwYO/ee880bce41.png by only clicking on one of them. Like, I click on the X and it turns into Y and the Y it's "connected" to turns into X.

Comment: Ok. Then just changing the text would do.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too. But I'm having trouble figuring out how I could change the texts on both buttons by clicking on just one of them?

Comment: For that you need to have some method to store which button is the corresponding pair of the other one. You need to get the pair button object. May be you can put all the button object in an array and use the index to map the pair relation.